SAXParseException in Blog Template: 'meta' tag not properly closed (XML Error)
I am not a coder at all, but I need some specific and to the point solution for the error which is outlined below:
"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 120; columnNumber: 3; The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
The image shown is a part of the xml code of a blogger.com template.
Please help me at your earliest.
Thanks and Regards,
Aquil
I have pasted the entire code for creating a blog in "blogger.com" and I am trying to get the solution of the error as mentioned in the image above (boxed in black) enter image description here

Please don't paste images of code. Anyway, the meta tag should be above the head tag and you are not showing that code in your image. Please paste the code here from Line 1 onwards as code using <> button in  the editor. You can [edit] your question here: [edit]. Also please read [mre]

It looks like maybe you need to close your <img> tag.
like so: <img src="src-url-here" alt="alt-text-here" />
that '/' is important. You'll generally always need it, if there's no closing tag for the element.
More detail:
In XML/HTML, information is structured with the use of elements. elements are defined by starting and ending tags
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
Some elements don't have anything that goes between the tags. For these, you can mostly use self-closing tags, which have the slash before the end of the tag, like so:
<br/>
the img tag can never have nested elements, so it is always a self-closing tag.

There's a difference between HTML and XML. In HTML, some elements (tags) such as img and meta are "empty by definition" and don't need a closing tag. In XML all elements need to be explicitly closed, using either the notation <meta/> or <meta>...</meta>. It looks like your input is HTML, but you are trying to parse it with an XML parser.
